# Tabulator select rows range with shift not working

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have a tabulator table with selectable:true, in its definition. However there is a problem: Holding the shift button down and dragging does NOT select multiple rows. I tried with: selectableRangeMode:"click" and/or selectableRollingSelection:true, without any effect. Note that I style the even/odd rows via CSS: .tabulator .tabulator-tableHolder .tabulator-table .tabulator-row.tabulator-row-odd{... if that has any effect. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you holding Shift before you begin clicking and dragging?

Comment: I have tried both. Neither works. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does it work for you on the example page: http://tabulator.info/examples/4.2#selectable ?
Hold Shift, then click and drag.  Do you have some code of your that you can share?

Comment: Alas Not. It doesn't work on the sample page either if using Firefox. However it works in Chrome for the sample and for my code. I need to support Firefox as well. But at least I have found it works in Chrome! Thanks. Any idea about Firefox issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not working for me in Firefox either.  I am using Firefox Quantum v64.0.2 (64-bit) on Linux.

There also seems to be a GitHub Issue already for this: https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/1803

The developer is very responsive and hopes to have a fix in a future build.  He alludes to it being a Firefox issue for which someone filed a Firefox bug report and he also suggests click functionality to be the most consistent experience.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will keep my eyes open for the Firefox fix. Also talking about issues. When I have a textarea in one of the columns the scroll is messed up (i.e. jumpy and partly empty page). Any idea? Thanks so much.

Comment: Sorry, but there isn't enough information to go on.  You should really create a new StackOverflow question for a new issue and hopefully paste some example code or a link to a jsfiddle.net (or the like) example you create so everyone can see the issue you are describing.  Don't forget to mark answers as accepted if you have found a resolution.

Comment: Thanks haferje. You are correct. I am a newbie to stackoverflow. I will post a separate question.  I marked your answer as accepted.